Question of building codes with Mvapich 3.0 Fortran 90 interface
I am using Mvapich-3.0 to build F90 parallel codes. Now with gfortran version >= 10, the compiler always complains the following "Type mismatch" error:
Compilation command:
mpif90 -I/opt/mvapich/include -c reduce.f90
Error message:
reduce.f90:27:27:

   12 |         call MPI_Allreduce(dv_src, dv, vlen, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
      |                           2
......
   27 |         call MPI_Allreduce(zv_src, zv, vlen, MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX, &
      |                           1
Error: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (COMPLEX(8)/REAL(8)).
reduce.f90:27:35:

   12 |         call MPI_Allreduce(dv_src, dv, vlen, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
      |                                   2
......
   27 |         call MPI_Allreduce(zv_src, zv, vlen, MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX, &
      |                                   1
Error: Type mismatch between actual argument at (1) and actual argument at (2) (COMPLEX(8)/REAL(8)).

Source code: reduce.f90:
        subroutine reduceData_Dbl(dv, dv_src, vlen)
        include 'mpif.h'
!       ----------------------------------------------------------------
        double precision :: dv(*), dv_src(*)
        integer          :: vlen

        integer          :: i, ierr
!       ----------------------------------------------------------------
        call MPI_Allreduce(dv_src, dv, vlen, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                 MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
        end

        subroutine reduceData_Cpx(zv, zv_src, vlen)
        include 'mpif.h'
!       ----------------------------------------------------------------
        double complex :: zv(*), zv_src(*)
        integer        :: vlen

        integer        :: i, ierr
!       ----------------------------------------------------------------
        call MPI_Allreduce(zv_src, zv, vlen, MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX, &
                 MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
        end

Although we can add the -fallow-argument-mismatch option to bypass this error, but gfortran man page and documents suggest that this is highly discouraged. The proper way is to add use mpi for interface declaration, replacing the line include 'mpif.h' in the source code.
But for mvapich-3.0 specific, adding use mpi does not work. The same error message is still there. The only way to solve it, as my test so far, is adding use mpi_f08 instead. However, doing this many MPI specific handles have to be changed from type integer to the new data types, for example, TYPE(MPI_Comm), TYPE(MPI_Group), TYPE(MPI_Request), TYPE(MPI_Status), .... etc. When building a large software, e.g., BerkeleyGW, there are hundreds of F90 codes, each code may have thousands of lines, hence doing this is a terrible work. Further, in such a large software, even adding -fallow-argument-mismatch option cannot bypass the type mismatch error.
So my question, whether there is a way to bypass this error easily ? I suspect that adding use mpi should work, provided that it could supply the completed F90 interfaces of all subroutines. In addition, it seems that using use mpi we don't have to change the data types of the MPI handles. But for my test so far it cannot work. Is there anything wrong in my test ?

What do you mean by "Further, in such a large software, even adding -fallow-argument-mismatch option cannot bypass the type mismatch error."? The flag disables the error, as such I don't understand this comment.

t is only through use of the f08 module you are guaranteed to bring the appropriate interfaces into scope. The older mpi module does not have this guarantee; it is purely a quality of implementation issue , and I suspect is not actually possible in all cases

As seen, it's not possible to use the pre-F2008 module in this way with a compiler which insists on following the procedure reference rules of Fortran which go back decades. If you want to compile your illegal Fortran code with GCC 10+ you need to ask it nicely (with that option) or fix your code by using use mpi_f08. If your polite request to the compiler doesn't help, you'll need to show us a [mre]. Note that you can incrementally fix your broken code with techniques such as shown here.

The way to go is to modernize your applications and use mpi_f08. As pointed by Ian, you do not have to do this everywhere. Now if you are looking for a quick, easy and yet suboptimal way to handle legacy applications, use an older gfortran.

If your type mismatch errors in the code are not related to the MPI interfaces, then note also that there are styles of errors which GCC 10+ will refuse to compile even with that flag. The flag is to allow frequent hacks like those used in MPI work, not egregious errors or sloppy writing.

My current task is trying to build a large code BerkelyGW successfully. Although the manual told that the option -fallow-argument-mismatch bypasses the type mismatch error, but in building the BerkelyGW it just cannot work. The same error persists. I think there are other complications in the code which leads to this error. But unfortunately I cannot figure it out yet.

Thanks for your comments. If porting to use mpi_f08 is the correct way to go, I will try it.

This is an artifact of the mismatch between MPI's type-agnostic buffer arguments and the Fortran language limitations for interfaces prior to Fortran 2018.  gfortran is inferring the interface where one does not exist, or detecting a conflict with an incompatible interface (which I expect uses INTEGER).
https://www.open-mpi.org/papers/euro-pvmmpi-2005-fortran/euro-pvm-mpi-2005-fortran.pdf describes the issues with providing typed interfaces with the mpif.h and mpi module, which are solved in the mpi_f08 module, as noted in the comments by Gilles.
